# Creating a random seed per instance with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, random

I've searched everywhere but can't find an answer for this.
How do I change the seed value per instance I create so that all my instances appear different.
Right now they all use the same seed and create the same shape.

Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

[image]

Comment: I thought I would be able to use the index but that seems to return an error