# Nodes: How to distribute different dynamically created objects of a NodeGropup to individual points?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, dynamic

I've only recently started trying out the Blender software.
But I enjoy this great program every day.

I have the following problem:

My current goal is to dynamically create objects and display them on a grid at every point.
To do this, I have a NodeGroup and I am currently throwing it onto the grid via "Instance on Points".
Sure, they are instances and they are all the same.
But I don't want instances that always look the same, I want my special variations.

Attached is a simple Blender file. Which shows the problem. I want all visible objects to look different. (You can change the seed on the top layer and see how the objects always change at the same time)
How can I do that?

<- I don't want to create a collection with (in this case) 9 objects and then output them there via "Collection Info". All objects should really be created dynamically.

I've already searched my fingers to the bone with Google. Somehow nobody has the problem.

Can anyone help or does anyone have any tips?

Best regards

[image]

---

No, unfortunately that didn't help either. (If I didn't miss anything) I have rebuilt it directly.
Yes, they are already partly different, but it's not clear to me why it doesn't apply to everything (the offset for Extrude was apparently used, but not the selection of faces (by the way: in the first blendfile I used a wrong RandomValue for the selection... now it's correct= Boolean)

In short: what I want to do is of course more complex. In the end, however, I have a node group that creates an object, each of which is individual and I want to distribute them to points (each looking different)

Here is the main Node
[image: Here is the main Node]
Here the NodeGroup
[image: Here the NodeGroup]
here is the result, which unfortunately is not correct, or rather, not the way I would like it to be
[image: here is the result, which unfortunately is not correct, or rather, not the way I would like it to be]
I think the switch with the TimeFrame is unnecessary, we can remove it.
[image: I think the switch with the TimeFrame is unnecessary, you can remove it.]

The ID transfer and the seed are probably the key.
[image]

By the way: There is probably currently no native usage such as: "nodegroup on Points"? or „Geometry on Points“?
In my view, this is what will be implemented in the software first. Then with greater use and complexity also with instances (at the latest with the RepeatZone) But there should also be something "simple" with just mesh/geometry. I am curious to see if there is a solution for this.

What I could also imagine is that you position a kind of proxies, each of which has a corresponding ID and attributes, and then exchange them with Python for my nodegroup (using the attributes), but I would like it to be much simpler and nicer directly and only with nodes.

---

It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. But I am happy to be taught better.

[Creating a random seed per instance with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306718/creating-a-random-seed-per-instance-with-geometry-nodes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to distribute unique generated rocks on a surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309366/how-to-distribute-unique-generated-rocks-on-a-surface?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Geonodes unique instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306701/geonodes-unique-instances?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Geometry nodes: different instance parameters for each instance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304744/geometry-nodes-different-instance-parameters-for-each-instance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**some of the above entries are 1 month old, but are always linked to this post**

[How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters)

**and at this point the result** seems to be that it won't work. Solutions are also offered. But in my case, this would mean calculating all variations in advance and storing them in a collection (beforehand or on the fly with "Geometry to Instance". That would be about 5000 objects for an emergency solution. It's probably feasible now with the RepeatZone, but it's not nice.

Comment: what blender version r u using? the simple answer: you cannot change individual instances when instancing (except rotation, position, scale). You can use realize instances and change them afterwards e.g. via set position or whatever. If you r using a newer Blender version, you can use the repeat zone to achieve what you want.

Comment: and to your comment "I've already searched my fingers to the bone with Google." -> this questions was asked many (!) times alone here on Blender Stack exchange. So i have no idea how you are using google...but you should have found something...

Comment: The version used is 4.0
I am aware that rotation/position/scaling is possible when instantiating, which is why I deliberately mentioned dynamically created objects. Because I don't want mere scaling or position. I want to dynamically create and position an object at each point in a grid. Each individual object is different (and I don't mean rotation/position/scaling).

Hence the attached blend file. This clearly shows that it is something else (if you look at it).

Comment: The RepeatZone does not help me either, at least it is not clear to me what it is supposed to do and which step I should repeat with it.

@Chris: Where can I find an example? All examples revolve around exactly what you describe. But that's not what I want to do. Perhaps you could take a look at the file. Each of the 9 objects should be different (the NodeGroup should deliver the object in each case.

Comment: It is absolutely clear to me that it does not work via "Instances on Point" and also not via "realize Instances", because I am not interested in such simple things as rotation/position/scaling. And at that moment, the object is already created. The change should be made via the NodeGroup. 

The example you gave doesn't help, because it's only about a simple scale. In my blend file there is a NodeGroup which, when used individually, always creates other objects. This is exactly what should happen with the grid. 9 different objects. U

Answer (score 2):

an example is this:

[image]

Note: of course instead of the arc there could be your custom node group you made yourself. Problem is, that you cannot change the input values here via instance on points because they are round (no field values), but you can solve that problem via repeat zone like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

---

Update for your face selection:

you can try this:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: No, unfortunately that didn't help either. (If I didn't miss anything) I have rebuilt it directly.

Comment: then pls provide your adapted blend file, then i will check it out, thx.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you'll find something. (Duarte Farrajota Ramos) has rearranged my post a bit. It is now integrated at the top of the question.  There is also a second file there. 

By the way, I am still hoping that there is a native solution for this, since the 4.0 version is already quite new. Maybe someone has overlooked something and it does work.  I'm not sure whether anyone will bother to find a solution with Duare's changeover...

Comment: i updated my answer. Please click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you. thx.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten around to watching it yet. But I will. It's definitely going in the right direction for an "emergency solution". Thank you very much so far. I'll definitely get back to you.